# How to pass value (true or false) for sorting tabular data in Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, sql-order-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to determine the ascending/descending property of the ng-repeat by passing a value coming from a dropdown box.

I defined a variable called "asdc" whose value is determined by a dropdown box. This variable should determine if the table will be sorted ascending or descending. The variable already created in the AngularJS controller so I don`t post it here. I am pasting the codes below. It does not work this way. I am wondering what I am missing.

This is the table that I want to sort.

```
<tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies | limitTo: rowlimit | orderBy: sortby : adsc" >
<td>{{technology.name | uppercase}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is the drowdown box. It defines the value of adsc as true or false and passes the value to "adsc".

```
<select ng-model="adsc">
    <option value="true">Asc</option>
    <option value="false">Dsc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use ng-value, otherwise the value is the string 'true' or the string 'false', and both are truthy.

Comment: if that's correct @JBNizet you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Matthias you're right. I'll do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-options to bind to something other than a string:

In controller:

```
$scope.directions = [
  {
    value: false,
    label: 'Asc'
  },
  {
    value: true,
    label: 'Desc'
  }
];
```

In view:

```
<select name="direction" ng-model="adsc" 
        ng-options="direction.value as direction.label for direction in directions">
</select>
```

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqIY4843HcHqpslf0A0Z?p=preview) demonstrating its use.

Also, note that passing true will sort in descending order, not ascending.

Comment: I tried bu no luck. Actually, for `sortby` variable in the code, I only use `value=` and it works well (see below). I can easily pass the value and sort by technology name. But the ascending/descending attribute looks like you cannot pass the value in the same way.

       `<select ng-model="sortby">
            <option value="name">Technology</option>
        </select>`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation. The trick, as usual, is to use ng-options, instead of iterating over options. I amended my answer.